# create a hive table without specifying the column names and column types

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have huge dataset with 1000 columns stored on HDFS. I want to create a hive table to filter and work on the data.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tablename(
     var1 INT,var2 STRING, var2  STRING)
     COMMENT 'testbykasa'
     ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
     FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
     STORED AS TEXTFILE
     LOCATION '/folder1/';
```

For smaller no. of columns(~ 5-10), I manually specify the column name and column type. Is there a way to get hive create the table by inferring the column name and datatype, without manually specifying it.

Comment: What kind of queries did you had in mind for a table containning 1000 columns named var1..var1000?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz: I wanted to check the distinct values within each column. The number of rows is in the order of few billions. Traditional excel commands did not work. So, I moved the csv file to HDFS.

Comment: Classic XY problem. Take a look at http://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 2):

#### Demo

mydata.csv

```
2,2,8,1,5,1,8,1,4,1,3,4,9,2,8,2,6,5,3,1,5,5,8,0,1,6,0,7,1,4
2,6,8,7,7,9,9,3,8,7,3,1,9,1,7,5,9,7,1,2,5,7,0,5,1,2,6,4,0,4
0,0,1,3,6,5,6,2,4,2,4,9,0,4,9,8,1,0,2,8,4,7,8,3,9,7,8,9,5,5
3,4,9,1,8,7,4,2,1,0,4,3,1,4,6,6,7,4,9,9,6,7,9,5,2,2,8,0,2,9
3,4,8,9,9,1,5,2,7,4,7,1,4,9,8,9,3,3,2,3,3,5,4,8,6,5,8,8,6,4
4,0,6,9,3,2,4,2,9,4,6,8,8,2,6,7,1,7,3,1,6,6,5,2,9,9,4,6,9,7
7,0,9,3,7,6,5,5,7,2,4,2,7,4,6,1,0,9,8,2,5,7,1,4,0,4,3,9,4,3
2,8,3,7,7,3,3,6,9,3,5,5,0,7,5,3,6,2,9,0,8,2,3,0,6,2,4,3,2,6
3,2,0,8,8,8,1,8,4,0,5,2,5,0,2,0,4,1,2,2,1,0,2,8,6,7,2,2,7,0
0,5,9,1,0,3,1,9,3,6,2,1,5,0,6,6,3,8,2,8,0,0,1,9,1,5,5,2,4,8
```

---

```
create external table mycsv (rec string) 
row format delimited
stored as textfile
tblproperties ('serialization.last.column.takes.rest'='true')
;
```

---

```
select      pe.pos + 1              as col
           ,count(distinct pe.val)  as count_distinct_val

from        mycsv
            lateral view posexplode(split(rec,',')) pe

group by    pe.pos  
;
```

---

```
+------+---------------------+
| col  | count_distinct_val  |
+------+---------------------+
| 1    | 5                   |
| 2    | 6                   |
| 3    | 6                   |
| 4    | 5                   |
| 5    | 7                   |
| 6    | 8                   |
| 7    | 7                   |
| 8    | 7                   |
| 9    | 6                   |
| 10   | 7                   |
| 11   | 6                   |
| 12   | 7                   |
| 13   | 7                   |
| 14   | 6                   |
| 15   | 6                   |
| 16   | 9                   |
| 17   | 7                   |
| 18   | 9                   |
| 19   | 5                   |
| 20   | 6                   |
| 21   | 7                   |
| 22   | 5                   |
| 23   | 8                   |
| 24   | 7                   |
| 25   | 5                   |
| 26   | 6                   |
| 27   | 7                   |
| 28   | 8                   |
| 29   | 8                   |
| 30   | 8                   |
+------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, but not with SQL script. To do this I use a Python script that read the first line of the csv file and create a script dynamically sending to Hive using the pyhive library (and erasing the first line of the csv). To identify the types, is just use Python functions to discovery if is a String, a Number etc.
The problem with Python is that it just work on Python 2.7, so I recommend you considere try to do the same code on Scala.

Comment: Can you post any reference articles for this?

Comment: Sorry, this knowledge came from my professional experience. I haven't read in any place, just developed for my self.